# set the Columns of a TableRow in a TableLayout

Tags: android, gridview, data-binding, android-tablelayout

well basicly I'm getting data from a database and I want to adapt this data in a kind of "DataGridView" on any other lenguaje, Basicly I have an GridView in a Main layout define like this:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gastoGridView"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dip"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dip" />
```

other hand I have a second xml layout file than define every item(row) for this gridView, It is my item_gridview xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView  android:text="@string/hello"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fechaAtt"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_gravity="left" />

            <TextView  android:text="@string/hello"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/descpAtt"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView  android:text="@string/hello"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/saldoAtt"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Ok, basicly I'm getting 3 attributes from database, I already developed the adapter to this gridview, so I show the information on it, but not in the way I want, I'll try to explain you, Currently it's being show like this

```
|     Date    |        Description        |      Price     |
 2014-11-17 any description it have 50.85$
```

I'm trying to divide my tablerow (width:fill_parent) on 3 sections(columns) I'm not sure if It's possible, because I'm not very involved on this subject, but I want to divide this tablerow on those 3 section, I want a small section on the left side of the row which will be my date, a large section in the center_horizontal wich will be my Description, and another left section wich will be my price, I'm not sure if you guys get my point but I want some like this.

```
|    Date       |          Description               |      Price      |
  2014-11-17      Get the description Centered Here        50.85$
```

I've tried to use the layout_span and layout_column on every TextView, but I get a Null Pointer error which I don't understand, maybe I'm doing that in a wrong way.

Could you guys help me to get this style? I've been reading about it a lot, It's a kind of difficult because Android do not support an DataGridView tool as others lenguages do.

Thanks you beforehand, I really need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your difficulty stems from the fact that your trying to bring your concept of the DataGridView into Android which is problematic. What you really want to do use a [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) with a proper `Adapter` and `Loader` (use a `Loader` if possible).

Now, with a [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) what happens is it creates `View` for every row returned from the `Cursor` using the `Adapter` to create (inflate) this view and populate it (binding). This is useful since you can now think about each row as a set of three items and lay them out appropriately. I recommend just using the regular [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) with the appropriate `layout_weight` set for your layout. You'll have to remember to set the [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) to horizontal.

Edit:

For clarification. With [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) you can specify in the layout.xml file the `android:layout_weight` parameter. This allows you to set 'relative' sizes (width or height depending on horizontal or vertical [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)). Once you do this the `android:layout_width` is ignored but you should set it to 0dp. An Example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now you have three `TextView` in a horizontal `LinearLayout` each with a weight set to `1`. That would make them all equal size. You can adjust the weight values to change their relative sizes to each other and the parent width.

Comment: I've already tried thw linearLayout way, my problem with this method, is than It's not responsive, I mean,  I have to set a witdh to every column or textview right? To get the view I want  but when i turn my phone to landscape mode  It doesnt get the fill parent width, i even tried to use dip instead dp, but it didnt work

Comment: If you don't use 'dp or dip' you are setting a desired 'relative' width and you let the LinearLayout determine the actual size. This 'relative' size is computed based on the (layout_width / sum(layout_width).

Comment: I'm not getting your point Qberticus, how could I set a width for each textView without using dp or dpi? In css i can do it with %, but not sure how to do it on android xml :s

Comment: Sorry, I meant weight not width like I mentioned in the actual answer. So, in your layout.xml: android:layout_weight="1" vs android:layout_width="100dp" the first one sets a relative width. If you added up all the other layout_weight settings and it totaled 3 then it would get 1/3 of the total width available. This is different from using weight with 'dp' which tells android to make it 100 device independent pixels.

Comment: thank you so much Qberticus, That was exactly what I was looking, a  row split on 3 sections, I didn't know about weight, I tried with dip width, but on landscape I didn't work as I expect, but now I know how to split things responsive, really thank, you solution was helpfully